# SQL reporting service and language problem

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am encountering a problem when attempting to display Hebrew fonts in SQL Server Reporting Services.

I see the fonts perfectly in the database, but when displaying the report all the Hebrew fonts displayed as ?????

Any suggestions?

Comment: What format are you displaying the report in: PDF, web, etc?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a browser issue? The render format is very important as well like rexem asked.

Answer (score 1):

Set the language for the report properties as He-IL. that should fix your problem

Comment: he-IL, with lower case he, I think